# How do I get a non-unicode string from the database with Django?

Tags: python, django, unicode

Using Django, I'm trying to write a view that compares the submission via a form (`request.POST['item']`) to whatever is already in the database in that row.

I am using `Entry.objects.values_list('item', flat=True)`, but that gives me a list of `unicode` objects which throws off the comparison.

How can I get at these objects as a pure list, without `unicode`?

Comment: But they should *both* be `unicode`s...

Comment: hmmph. for whatever reason when use(request.POST['item']) I get just the string. with no fancy unicode on it. any idea why this is?

Comment: Try decoding it with the charset specified in the request's encoding header.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a little more?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-headers-charset

Comment: okay so i read it over and now know that there are different ways to encode the unicode but I'm struggling to bridge the link between that article and how the request is being decoded incorrectly?

Comment: If you "get just the string" then it *isn't* being decoded; you'll need to decode it yourself.

Comment: So the question becomes how do i decode it haha. I look around the docs and hopefully run into it.

Comment: http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Comment: Can you post the comparison code (including the rows where you get the values out of the POST dictionary) please?

Comment: its says that decoding the unicode object isnt support any idea what I need to import? @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: You don't decode `unicode`s. Read the presentation again.

Comment: whoops. I replied to the wrong comment thread. I guess it was with regard the other answer posted

Answer (score 1):

To create a `unicode` object, you can use

```
from settings import DEFAULT_CHARSET
s = unicode(request.POST['item'], request.encoding or DEFAULT_CHARSET)
```

Note that items inside `request.POST` should already be of type `unicode`, hence no conversion should be required.

```
In [1]: a = u'Täöüß'

In [2]: a
Out[2]: u'T\xe4\xf6\xfc\xdf'

In [3]: type(a)
Out[3]: unicode
```

The following will work as `unicode` does not have to do anything:

```
In [4]: unicode(a)
Out[4]: u'T\xe4\xf6\xfc\xdf'
```

Forcing `unicode` to decode from `utf-8` encoding, however, must fail as `a` is not an 8-bit string but a `unicode` variable:

```
In [5]: unicode(a, 'utf-8')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 unicode(a, 'utf-8')

TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported
```

You can use `.encode(encoding)` on the `unicode` object to create 8-bit string versions:

```
In [6]: utf8 = a.encode('utf-8')

In [7]: latin1 = a.encode('latin-1')

In [8]: latin1
Out[8]: 'T\xe4\xf6\xfc\xdf'

In [9]: utf8
Out[9]: 'T\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc\xc3\x9f'
```

Note that the resulting strings are of type `str` and **not** of type `unicode`.

If you are given `str`-typed data and know the corresponding encoding, you can create `unicode` objects like this:

```
In [10]: b = unicode(latin1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 b = unicode(latin1)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 1:
 ordinal not in range(128)
```

This has to fail as no encoding is given which means a default encoding of `ascii` is assumed (which, of course, cannot handle `0xe4`).

```
In [11]: b = unicode(latin1, 'utf-8')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 b = unicode(latin1, 'utf-8')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 1:
 invalid continuation byte
```

Using a wrong encoding, in this case trying to decode from `utf-8` when working on a `latin-1` string, will also raise a `UnicodeDecodeError`.

```
In [12]: b = unicode(latin1, 'latin-1')
```

Using the right encoding will allow to create a `unicode` object for the given `str` instance. `b` is equal to `a`:

```
In [13]: b == a
Out[13]: True
```

Using this information you should be able to create `unicode` instances wherever you need them and thus compare `request.POST` data with values from your database.

More information on  Unicode handling in Python is available here http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

Django's documentation on Unicode data can be found here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/

Hope that helps.

Comment: it says that I can't import DEFAULT_CHARSET

Comment: Check if DEFAULT_CHARSET is defined; or use ...request.encoding or "utf-8") instead.